# Populating item count of cart in php

Tags: php

I am having a cart page and I want to display the item count inside the brackets in `<h4>` tags.

The problem is that it will always display zero because it is above the codes. Also, it is hard to reorder the codes because of PHP process codes from top to bottom.

I can't find a way to do that. How could I do that?

```
// some codes

if($cart_id != ''){
   $cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
   $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
   $items = json_decode($result['items'],true);
   $i = 1;
   $sub_total = 0;
   $item_count = 0;
 }
 ?>

<h2 style="color:#00484F;">Cart(<?=$item_count?>)</h2>

// some codes

<?php
             foreach($items as $item){
               $product_id = $item['id'];
               $productQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '{$product_id}'");
               $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);
               $sArray = explode(',',$product['ages']);
               foreach($sArray as $ageString){
                 $s = explode(':',$ageString);
                 if($s[0] == $item['age']){
                   $available = $s[1];
                 }
               }
               ?>

// some codes

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" id="button1" onclick="update_cart('removeone','<?=$product['id'];?>','<?=$item['age'];?>');">-</button>
                     </span>
                  <span class="boxed6">
                   <?=$item['quantity'];?>
                 </span>
                   <?php if($item['quantity'] < $available): ?>
                     <span class="boxed7">
                     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" id="button2" onclick="update_cart('addone','<?=$product['id'];?>','<?=$item['age'];?>');">+</button>
                     </span>
                   <?php else: ?>
                     <span class="text-danger">Max</span>
                   <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>
                   <p class="text-right" style="margin-right:50px; color:#1C5D6B;"><?=money($item['quantity'] * $product['price']);?></p>
                   <hr>
              <?php
                $i++;
                $item_count += $item['quantity'];
                $sub_total += ($product['price'] * $item['quantity']);
              }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the item count up front by summing it separately using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the quantity values and [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to sum them. Based on your code, this should work:

```
$item_count = array_sum(array_column($items, 'quantity'));
```

Use this where you currently have `$item_count = 0;`

Comment: I've discovered a problem not related to $item_count = array_sum(array_column($items, 'quantity'));. If I deleted the cart in my database I'm getting an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 125. This problem will only be fixed until if I deleted the cookie from my browser... How to fix this ??

Comment: @MyDB you should ask a new question. It requires too much information to be able to put it in a comment